# Check PasswordBox text contains char and number

Tags: c#, wpf, contains, passwordbox

I'm creating a WPF window for insert user, I'm using `PasswordBox` for user type your password, but I have not ideas what I can put in `passBox.Password.Contains( )`

I need help for how to check this `PasswordBox` contains chars and numbers?

Comment: I have tried  passBox.Password.Contains()   but I have not ideas what I need put in Contains

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Contains` is the wrong method.

Here:

```
bool isValidPassword = passBox.Password.Any(char.IsDigit) 
                           && passBox.Password.Any(char.IsLetter);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use regular expression to check it. It will be something like this:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

Regex regex = new Regex(@"^.*(?=.{4,10})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).*$");
if (regex.Match(passwordBox1.Password).Success)
{
  //the password match the rule
}
```

The above regular expression matches if:

1. Search for at least one digit in any position
2. Search for at least one upper or lower case in any position
3. Enforce password to consist of 4-10 characters

You can modify it to fit your needs

Comment: Thank you very much too! I like this solution too